# how to delete multiple ssas database using xmla script

Tags: ssas

how to delete multiple SSAS database using XMLA script

if possible please post me with syntax

Comment: What did you try? Did you consult the documentation for the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple XMLA commands in a [batch tag](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186692%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), try something like this:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine" Transaction="true">
<Delete xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
      <Object> 
          <DatabaseID>DB1</DatabaseID>
      </Object>
</Delete>
<Delete xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
     <Object> 
         <DatabaseID>DB2</DatabaseID>
     </Object>
</Delete>
</Batch>
```